# Group Video call using WebRTC and Socket in Android Java

Tags: android, android-studio, socket.io, webrtc, video-streaming

I have achieved one to one peer connection, but i want to implement for Group video call

JAVA code for one to one peer connection

```
package com.example.nehby.bottomnav.club;

import static com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.Socket.EVENT_CONNECT;
import static com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT;
import static org.webrtc.SessionDescription.Type.ANSWER;
import static org.webrtc.SessionDescription.Type.OFFER;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.VideoView;


import com.example.nehby.R;
import com.example.nehby.server.SimpleSdpObserver;
import com.example.nehby.server.SocketIOManager;
import com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.IO;
import com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.Socket;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.webrtc.AudioSource;
import org.webrtc.AudioTrack;
import org.webrtc.Camera1Enumerator;
import org.webrtc.Camera2Enumerator;
import org.webrtc.CameraEnumerator;
import org.webrtc.DataChannel;

import org.webrtc.EglBase;
import org.webrtc.IceCandidate;
import org.webrtc.MediaConstraints;
import org.webrtc.MediaStream;
import org.webrtc.PeerConnection;
import org.webrtc.PeerConnectionFactory;
import org.webrtc.RtpReceiver;
import org.webrtc.SessionDescription;
import org.webrtc.SurfaceTextureHelper;
import org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer;
import org.webrtc.VideoCapturer;
import org.webrtc.VideoRenderer;
import org.webrtc.VideoSource;
import org.webrtc.VideoTrack;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import pub.devrel.easypermissions.AfterPermissionGranted;
import pub.devrel.easypermissions.EasyPermissions;

public class ClubRoomActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Socket socket;



private static final String TAG = ClubRoomActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private static final int CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
private static final String SERVER_URL = "http://your-backend-server-url.com";
private static final String ROOM_ID = "your-room-id";


private static final int RC_CALL = 111;
public static final String VIDEO_TRACK_ID = "ARDAMSv0";
public static final int VIDEO_RESOLUTION_WIDTH = 1280;
public static final int VIDEO_RESOLUTION_HEIGHT = 720;
public static final int FPS = 30;
private boolean isInitiator;
private boolean isChannelReady;
private boolean isStarted;


MediaConstraints audioConstraints;
MediaConstraints videoConstraints;
MediaConstraints sdpConstraints;
VideoSource videoSource;
VideoTrack localVideoTrack;
AudioSource audioSource;
AudioTrack localAudioTrack;
SurfaceTextureHelper surfaceTextureHelper;

private PeerConnection peerConnection;
private EglBase rootEglBase;
private PeerConnectionFactory factory;
private VideoTrack videoTrackFromCamera;

@BindView(R.id.surface_view1)
SurfaceViewRenderer surface_view1;

@BindView(R.id.surface_view2)
SurfaceViewRenderer surface_view2;

@BindView(R.id.surface_view3)
SurfaceViewRenderer surface_view3;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_club_room);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
    }
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, 2);
    }

    start();
}

@AfterPermissionGranted(RC_CALL)
private void start() {
    String[] perms = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO};
    if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, perms)) {
        connectToSignallingServer();

        initializeSurfaceViews();

        initializePeerConnectionFactory();

        createVideoTrackFromCameraAndShowIt();

        initializePeerConnections();

        startStreamingVideo();
    } else {
        EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this, "Need some permissions", RC_CALL, perms);
    }
}

private void connectToSignallingServer() {
    try {
        // For me this was "http://192.168.1.220:3000";
        // $ hostname -I
        String URL = "http://10.173.1.175:3030/";// "https://calm-badlands-59575.herokuapp.com/"; //
        Log.e(TAG, "REPLACE ME: IO Socket:" + URL);
        socket = SocketIOManager.getSocket();
        socket.emit("create or join", "Lerry");
        socket.on(EVENT_CONNECT, args -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "connectToSignallingServer: connect");

        }).on("ipaddr", args -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "connectToSignallingServer: ipaddr");
        }).on("created", args -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "connectToSignallingServer: created");
            isInitiator = true;
        }).on("full", args -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "connectToSignallingServer: full");
        }).on("join", args -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "connectToSignallingServer: join");
            Log.d(TAG, "connectToSignallingServer: Another peer made a request to join room");
            Log.d(TAG, "connectToSignallingServer: This peer is the initiator of room");
            isChannelReady = true;
        }).on("joined", args -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "connectToSignallingServer: joined");
            isChannelReady = true;
        }).on("log", args -> {
            for (Object arg : args) {
                Log.d(TAG, "connectToSignallingServer: " + String.valueOf(arg));
            }
        }).on("message", args -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "connectToSignallingServer: got a message");
        }).on("message", args -> {
            try {
                if (args[0] instanceof String) {
                    String message = (String) args[0];
                    if (message.equals("got user media")) {
                        maybeStart();
                    }
                } else {
                    JSONObject message = (JSONObject) args[0];
                    Log.d(TAG, "connectToSignallingServer: got message " + message);
                    if (message.getString("type").equals("offer")) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "connectToSignallingServer: received an offer " + isInitiator + " " + isStarted);
                        if (!isInitiator && !isStarted) {
                            maybeStart();
                        }
                        peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new SimpleSdpObserver(), new SessionDescription(OFFER, message.getString("sdp")));
                        doAnswer();
                    } else if (message.getString("type").equals("answer") && isStarted) {
                        peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new SimpleSdpObserver(), new SessionDescription(ANSWER, message.getString("sdp")));
                    } else if (message.getString("type").equals("candidate") && isStarted) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "connectToSignallingServer: receiving candidates");
                        IceCandidate candidate = new IceCandidate(message.getString("id"), message.getInt("label"), message.getString("candidate"));
                        peerConnection.addIceCandidate(candidate);
                    }
                    /*else if (message === 'bye' && isStarted) {
                    handleRemoteHangup();
                }*/
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).on(EVENT_DISCONNECT, args -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "connectToSignallingServer: disconnect");
        });
        socket.connect();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void doAnswer() {
    peerConnection.createAnswer(new SimpleSdpObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onCreateSuccess(SessionDescription sessionDescription) {
            peerConnection.setLocalDescription(new SimpleSdpObserver(), sessionDescription);
            JSONObject message = new JSONObject();
            try {
                message.put("type", "answer");
                message.put("sdp", sessionDescription.description);
                sendMessage(message);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new MediaConstraints());
}

private void maybeStart() {
    Log.d(TAG, "maybeStart: " + isStarted + " " + isChannelReady);
    if (!isStarted && isChannelReady) {
        isStarted = true;
        if (isInitiator) {
            doCall();
        }
    }
}

private void doCall() {
    MediaConstraints sdpMediaConstraints = new MediaConstraints();

    sdpMediaConstraints.mandatory.add(
            new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("OfferToReceiveAudio", "true"));
    sdpMediaConstraints.mandatory.add(
            new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("OfferToReceiveVideo", "true"));
    peerConnection.createOffer(new SimpleSdpObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onCreateSuccess(SessionDescription sessionDescription) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreateSuccess: ");
            peerConnection.setLocalDescription(new SimpleSdpObserver(), sessionDescription);
            JSONObject message = new JSONObject();
            try {
                message.put("type", "offer");
                message.put("sdp", sessionDescription.description);
                sendMessage(message);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, sdpMediaConstraints);
}

private void sendMessage(Object message) {
    socket.emit("message", message);
}

private void initializeSurfaceViews() {
    rootEglBase = EglBase.create();
    surface_view1.init(rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext(), null);
    surface_view1.setEnableHardwareScaler(true);
    surface_view1.setMirror(true);

    surface_view2.init(rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext(), null);
    surface_view2.setEnableHardwareScaler(true);
    surface_view2.setMirror(true);

    surface_view3.init(rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext(), null);
    surface_view3.setEnableHardwareScaler(true);
    surface_view3.setMirror(true);

    //add one more
}

private void initializePeerConnectionFactory() {
    PeerConnectionFactory.initializeAndroidGlobals(this, true, true, true);
    factory = new PeerConnectionFactory(null);
    factory.setVideoHwAccelerationOptions(rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext(), rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext());
}

private void createVideoTrackFromCameraAndShowIt() {
    audioConstraints = new MediaConstraints();
    VideoCapturer videoCapturer = createVideoCapturer();
    VideoSource videoSource = factory.createVideoSource(videoCapturer);
    videoCapturer.startCapture(VIDEO_RESOLUTION_WIDTH, VIDEO_RESOLUTION_HEIGHT, FPS);

    videoTrackFromCamera = factory.createVideoTrack(VIDEO_TRACK_ID, videoSource);
    videoTrackFromCamera.setEnabled(true);
    videoTrackFromCamera.addRenderer(new VideoRenderer(surface_view1));

    //create an AudioSource instance
    audioSource = factory.createAudioSource(audioConstraints);
    localAudioTrack = factory.createAudioTrack("101", audioSource);
}


private void initializePeerConnections() {
    peerConnection = createPeerConnection(factory);
}

private void startStreamingVideo() {
    MediaStream mediaStream = factory.createLocalMediaStream("ARDAMS");
    mediaStream.addTrack(videoTrackFromCamera);
    mediaStream.addTrack(localAudioTrack);
    peerConnection.addStream(mediaStream);

    sendMessage("got user media");
}

List<MediaStream> streams;
private PeerConnection createPeerConnection(PeerConnectionFactory factory) {
    ArrayList<PeerConnection.IceServer> iceServers = new ArrayList<>();
    String URL = "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302";
    iceServers.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer(URL));

    PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration rtcConfig = new PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration(iceServers);
    MediaConstraints pcConstraints = new MediaConstraints();


    streams = new ArrayList<>();

    PeerConnection.Observer pcObserver = new PeerConnection.Observer() {
        @Override
        public void onSignalingChange(PeerConnection.SignalingState signalingState) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onSignalingChange: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onIceConnectionChange(PeerConnection.IceConnectionState iceConnectionState) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onIceConnectionChange: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onIceConnectionReceivingChange(boolean b) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onIceConnectionReceivingChange: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onIceGatheringChange(PeerConnection.IceGatheringState iceGatheringState) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onIceGatheringChange: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onIceCandidate(IceCandidate iceCandidate) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onIceCandidate: ");
            JSONObject message = new JSONObject();

            try {
                message.put("type", "candidate");
                message.put("label", iceCandidate.sdpMLineIndex);
                message.put("id", iceCandidate.sdpMid);
                message.put("candidate", iceCandidate.sdp);

                Log.d(TAG, "onIceCandidate: sending candidate " + message);
                sendMessage(message);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onIceCandidatesRemoved(IceCandidate[] iceCandidates) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onIceCandidatesRemoved: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAddStream(MediaStream mediaStream) {
            streams.add(mediaStream);

            if (streams.size() == 1){
                Log.d(TAG, "onAddStream: " + mediaStream.videoTracks.size());
                VideoTrack remoteVideoTrack = mediaStream.videoTracks.get(0);
                AudioTrack remoteAudioTrack = mediaStream.audioTracks.get(0);
                remoteAudioTrack.setEnabled(true);
                remoteVideoTrack.setEnabled(true);
                remoteVideoTrack.addRenderer(new VideoRenderer(surface_view2));
            }

            if (streams.size() == 2){
                Log.d(TAG, "onAddStream: " + mediaStream.videoTracks.size());
                VideoTrack remoteVideoTrack = mediaStream.videoTracks.get(0);
                AudioTrack remoteAudioTrack = mediaStream.audioTracks.get(0);
                remoteAudioTrack.setEnabled(true);
                remoteVideoTrack.setEnabled(true);
                remoteVideoTrack.addRenderer(new VideoRenderer(surface_view3));
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onRemoveStream(MediaStream mediaStream) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onRemoveStream: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onDataChannel(DataChannel dataChannel) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChannel: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onRenegotiationNeeded() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onRenegotiationNeeded: ");
        }
    };

    return factory.createPeerConnection(rtcConfig, pcConstraints, pcObserver);
}

private VideoCapturer createVideoCapturer() {
    VideoCapturer videoCapturer;
    if (useCamera2()) {
        videoCapturer = createCameraCapturer(new Camera2Enumerator(this));
    } else {
        videoCapturer = createCameraCapturer(new Camera1Enumerator(true));
    }
    return videoCapturer;
}

private VideoCapturer createCameraCapturer(CameraEnumerator enumerator) {
    final String[] deviceNames = enumerator.getDeviceNames();

    for (String deviceName : deviceNames) {
        if (enumerator.isFrontFacing(deviceName)) {
            VideoCapturer videoCapturer = enumerator.createCapturer(deviceName, null);

            if (videoCapturer != null) {
                return videoCapturer;
            }
        }
    }

    for (String deviceName : deviceNames) {
        if (!enumerator.isFrontFacing(deviceName)) {
            VideoCapturer videoCapturer = enumerator.createCapturer(deviceName, null);

            if (videoCapturer != null) {
                return videoCapturer;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}

private boolean useCamera2() {
    return Camera2Enumerator.isSupported(this);
}


boolean isCameraPermissionGranted;
boolean isAudioPermissionGranted;

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            isCameraPermissionGranted = true;

        } else {
            // Camera permission denied
        }
    }
    if (requestCode == 2) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Camera permission granted, you can now open the camera
            isAudioPermissionGranted = true;

        } else {
            // Camera permission denied
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    socket.emit("bye");
}
}
```

Give me some suggestion how can i update my code accordingly?
i'm using my Nodejs server where by using socket i'm sending the peers data back to Android.

Looking for the help so i can implement the Group Video call